# flatten/concat-aggregate JSONB array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have a `JSONB` column that contains JSON arrays. I now need to get all distinct values from all rows into one single array.

Input:

```
id | values
-----------
1  | [x, y, z]
2  | [a, b, x]
```

Desired output:

```
result
---------------
[a, b, x, y, z]
```

I can't just use `jsonb_agg` with `DISTINCT` because that would return a 2-dimensional array, and I can't find any flatten or concat aggregate functions. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should unnest the arrays before using the aggregate:

```
with my_table(id, data) as (
values
    (1, '["x", "y", "z"]'::jsonb),
    (2, '["a", "b", "x"]')
)

select jsonb_agg(distinct value)
from my_table, jsonb_array_elements_text(data);

         jsonb_agg         
---------------------------
 ["a", "b", "x", "y", "z"]
(1 row)
```

---

You can group the results:

```
with my_table(id, data) as (
values
    (1, '["x", "y", "z"]'::jsonb),
    (1, '["a", "b", "x"]'),
    (2, '["1", "2", "3"]'),
    (2, '["2", "3", "4"]')
)

select id, jsonb_agg(distinct value)
from my_table, jsonb_array_elements_text(data)
group by id;

 id |         jsonb_agg         
----+---------------------------
  1 | ["a", "b", "x", "y", "z"]
  2 | ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is any way of using this approach inside a window function? (Like to combine all arrays of rows that have same `id`.)

Comment: You do not need a window function, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about distinct elements, then you could define you own aggregator

```
CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_concat_agg (jsonb)
(
    sfunc = jsonb_concat,
    stype = jsonb,
    initcond = '[]'
);
```

Then it would be

```
SELECT jsonb_concat_agg(values);
```

The result would be

```
result
---------------
[a, b, x, x, y, z]
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not really, here [a, b, x] and [x,y, z] are distinct. He is interested in distinct elements of the arrays, not in distinct arrays